# How to search for web and images results from Google Custom Search JSON API?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm implementing [Google's Custom Search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction) into my application which shall search for both web and images. I am able to query for web and images independently.
For web: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${key}&start=${start}&cx=${cx}&q=${searchVal}` 
For images: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${key}&searchType=image&start=${start}&cx=${cx}&q=${searchVal}` 
This works perfectly. However, as you can see, I have to make 2 separate requests to get the web results and the images for a single query value. This is an issue since it makes room for [Google's search query quota](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?hl=ro#pricing) to be exceeded. So, I need to find a way to make a single request which returns me both the web and image results for a particular search value. 
 Any help or recommendation would be appreciated.